# Creating addition <select> boxes after clicking 'Add'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on room management application that will allow the user to choose a room, then either confirm (by clicking a button), or add another room to book (clicking another button).

I have successfully implemented the drop down list connected to a picture viewer.

The user should be allowed to click the 'add' button and the first  list should be disabled (which I know how to do), while another  box appears to book another room (which I do not know how to do).

My guess is using arrays, but I cannot get my head on how to properly implement this situation.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this website. I posted the question by accident without showing my code. How do I edit my question? It's quite strange that I don't see an edit button. I would like to add whatever little code I had to show just to get an idea...

Comment: Yes, your guess is ok... Btw, how many rooms are there? If there are more than two, you need flexible solution... Click 'Edit' and add code, you will notice code button in editor....